# Select rows of a data frame based on string match then sum and transform those rows

Tags: r, transform, lapply

I have a list of 18 data frames, each one with a different number of rows and random blank rows throughout, structured like this:

```
    l = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D2", "", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D3")
    a = c("Al", "Al", "St", "", "St", "Un", "St", "Al", "Al", "St", "St", "", "Al", "Al", "St", "St")
    b = c(6000, 4980, 123, "", 98, 87, 51, 10989, 8756, 457, 233, "", 989, 743, 67, 55)
    mydf = data.frame("Location" = l, "Name" = a, "count" = b)
    mydf
        Location Name count
1        D1   Al  6000
2        D1   Al  4980
3        D1   St   123
4                     
5        D1   St    98
6        D1   Un    87
7        D1   St    51
8        D2   Al 10989
9        D2   Al  8756
10       D2   St   457
11       D2   St   233
12                    
13       D3   Al   989
14       D3   Al   743
15       D3   St    67
16       D3   St    55
```

My data with 18 data frames:

```
sapply(mydata, dim)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,]  171  146  132  147  149  148  138  143  114   111   115   101   112   218   122    96   156   128
[2,]   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10    10
```

I want to use `transform` to add a column to my data frame with the sum of the Al counts for each location. I plan on filling the entire new column with the same value.  I thought I could find those rows that contain the string "Al" and then apply the sum function but this isn't working.  Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
add.al.sum = function(df){
    als = df[grep("Al", df$Name),]
    alsum = sum(als, na.rm = TRUE)
    transform(df, Al.sum = c(alsum))
}
mydf = lapply(mydf, function(x) add.al.sum(x))
```

This doesn't do what I want.  I want my transformed data table to look like this; **preserving the blank lines is not necessary**.

```
Location Name count  Al.sum
1        D1   Al  6000     10980
2        D1   Al  4980     10980
3        D1   St   123     10980
4                          NA
5        D1   St    98     10980
6        D1   Un    87     10980
7        D1   St    51     10980
8        D2   Al 10989     19745
9        D2   Al  8756     19745
10       D2   St   457     19745
11       D2   St   233     19745 
12                         NA
13       D3   Al   989     1732
14       D3   Al   743     1732
15       D3   St    67     1732
16       D3   St    55     1732
```

It actually tells me `Error in df$Name : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.  The only difference between my real data and my example data is that the `count` column in my real data is listed as an `int` instead of a `num`.  I need this to work with the `int` values in the `count` column.

After I get the sums of the Al counts I will repeat the process to get the sums of the St and Un counts in their own respective columns.

EDIT:  I have expanded the example data and added a bit more information about the list of data frames I am working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses no packages and is only one line of code.  `(Name == 'Al') * count` equals `count` for those rows for which `Name` equals `'A1'` and equals 0 for those that are not.  (Alternately we could have replaced that expression with  `ifelse(Name == 'A1', count, 0)` ). We then use `ave` to sum them by `Location`.  Note that we are using `mydf0` defined in Note 2 at the bottom.

```
transform(mydf0, Al.sum = ave((Name == 'Al') * count, Location, FUN = sum))
```

giving:

```
   Location Name count Al.sum
1        D1   Al  6000  10980
2        D1   Al  4980  10980
3        D1   St   123  10980
4        D1   St    98  10980
5        D1   Un    87  10980
6        D1   St    51  10980
7        D2   Al 10989  19745
8        D2   Al  8756  19745
9        D2   St   457  19745
10       D2   St   233  19745
```

The example data had no NA values so we did not bother with the `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)` but if this is to be extended to other data where there are NA values that are to be removed then replace `sum` with `function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` .

**list**

The question mentions multiple data frames but does not give an example; so let us assume that we have the list `L` of data frames shown below.  Then:

```
L <- list(mydf0, mydf0)

lapply(L, transform, Al.sum = ave((Name == 'Al') * count, Location, FUN = sum))
```

**Note:**  We can fix the solution in the question like this. `grepl` results in a logical vector which is regarded as a 0/1 vector when multiplying so the non-Al counts are zeroed.  Then `by` applies this by `Location` and `rbind` puts the pieces (one per `Location`) together.

```
add.al.sum = function(df) {
    transform(df, Al.sum = sum(grepl("Al", Name) * count, na.rm = TRUE))
}
do.call("rbind", by(mydf0, mydf$Location, add.al.sum))
```

**Note 2:**  Fix up your data frames first:

```
mydf0 <- mydf # preserve mydf just in case
mydf0[] <- lapply(mydf0, as.character) # make all cols character
mydf0 <- transform(mydf0, count = as.numeric(count)) # make count numeric
mydf0 <- subset(mydf0, Location != "") # remove blank lines
```

Even easier might be to ensure that when you read in the data that you ignore blank lines and make the columns character but that would depend on how they are read in.

Comment: I like your approach of not needing another package.  I think I have one issue that I didn't show in my example data.  My data has blank rows.  So when I run `mydf= transform(mydf, Al.sum = ave((Name == "Al") * count, Location, FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)))`  I get this error message `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 171, 146, 132, 147, 149, 148, 138, 143, 114, 111, 115, 101, 112, 218, 122, 96, 156, 128`   Can you tell me how to get it to skip blank rows?

Comment: I see that my error message above is related to the fact that each data frame in my list has a different number of rows.  How do I get this to work for the different number of rows?

Comment: I have edited my question.  What I believe is my issue is that I am having trouble extending the answers to work with a list of data frames rather than on a single data frame.

Comment: See Note 2 and changes throughout to use `mydf0` instead of `mydf`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the list answer above.  It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
   group_by(Location) %>%
   mutate(Al.sum = sum(count[Name == 'Al']))

#Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#Groups: Location [2]

#   Location   Name count Al.sum
#     <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1        D1     Al  6000  10980
#2        D1     Al  4980  10980
#3        D1     St   123  10980
#4        D1     St    98  10980
#5        D1     Un    87  10980
#6        D1     St    51  10980
#7        D2     Al 10989  19745
#8        D2     Al  8756  19745
#9        D2     St   457  19745
#10       D2     St   233  19745
```

or via `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, Al.sum := sum(count[Name == 'Al']), by = Location]
```

Comment: Trying the dplyr method gives me this error message `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "list"`.  I guess because I am trying to apply this to a  list of data frames.